# django-log-viewer: LOG_VIEWER_FILES_PATTERN

Tags: django, logging, log-viewer

I have 2 types of log files, with various "filenames":

- filename.log
- filename.log.1

How to configure this in LOG_VIEWER_FILES_PATTERN?

This does not work:

LOG_VIEWER_FILES_PATTERN = "*.log??"

Note: django-log-viewer version 1.1.7